# window view leaked

Tags: java, android

```
public class ProgressCircleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_circle_activity);
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(ProgressCircleActivity.this);
        progressBar.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(3*1000);
                        Intent i=new Intent(ProgressCircleActivity.this,PhoneNumberLogin.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        //Remove activity
                        finish();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
            }).start();
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
10-05 16:12:22.577 27797-27797/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-05 16:12:32.397 27797-27797/com.example.dis015.meetdax2danish E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.dis015.meetdax2danish.ProgressCircleActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{25b6bc4a V.E..... R......D 0,0-501,174} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:520)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:287)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325)
        at com.example.dis015.meetdax2danish.ProgressCircleActivity.onCreate(ProgressCircleActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

This is my splashScreenActivity when i open the app is getting crash.But in some mobiles the app is not crashing.I dont know what is the issue please help me to sort out

Comment: please dismiss progress dialog in onDestroy method of SplashScreenActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not dismiss the progressbar so it is showing that leaked window message.
Before finishing the activity please dismiss the progressbar dialog.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_circle_activity);
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(ProgressCircleActivity.this);
        progressBar.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(3*1000);
                        Intent i=new Intent(ProgressCircleActivity.this,PhoneNumberLogin.class);
                        startActivity(i);//dismiss the progressdialog
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                        //Remove activity
                        finish();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
            }).start();
    }
```

Comment: @DeepaDinesh did u fix it??